# How to provide accurate TypeScript types for a flatListToHierarchical function?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

Here is a challenging problem for TypeScript lovers:

I want to provide accurate types for this following function:

```
const flatListToHierarchical = (
    data = [],
    {idKey='id',parentKey='parentId',childrenKey='children'} = {}
) => {
    const tree = [];
    const childrenOf = {};
    data.forEach((item) => {
        const newItem = {...item};
        const { [idKey]: id, [parentKey]: parentId = 0 } = newItem;
        childrenOf[id] = childrenOf[id] || [];
        newItem[childrenKey] = childrenOf[id];
        parentId
            ? (
                childrenOf[parentId] = childrenOf[parentId] || []
            ).push(newItem)
            : tree.push(newItem);
    });
    return tree;
};
```

So basically the `data` parameter should have a type of list of items but it must contain the values of the second parameter object: `{idKey='key',parentKey='parentId',childrenKey='children'}`

Say you call this function like:

```
export interface BlockType {
    __typename?: string;
    key: number | string;
    parentKey: number | string;
    innerBlocks?: Array<BlockType | null>;
    name?: string;
}

const blocks: BlockType[] = [
    {key: '1', parentKey: '2', innerBlocks: []}
];

const hierarchicalBlocks: BlockType[] = flatListToHierarchical( blocks, {idKey: 'key', parentKey: 'parentKey', childrenKey: 'innerBlocks'} );
```

Then both the type of `blocks` and the return type should match `ListNode[]` where:

```
type ListNode {
    key: number | string;
    parentKey: number | string;
    innerBlocks: Array<ListNode | null>
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

Now if you call this like:

```
export interface BlockType {
    __typename?: string;
    id: number | string;
    parentId: number | string;
    children?: Array<BlockType | null>;
    name?: string;
}

const blocks: BlockType[] = [
    {id: '1', parentId: '2', children: []}
];

const hierarchicalBlocks: BlockType[] = flatListToHierarchical( blocks );
```

Then the ListNode type would match:

```
type ListNode {
    id: number | string;
    parentId: number | string;
    children: ListNode[]
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

Since the default values from the second param object takes place.

So how to type this correctly in TypeScript?

I tried most of the examples in TypeScript advanced types docs but with no avail.

Then I tried to extract the values of an object as Union types but then I'm stuck now since I can't figure out how to convert it into a type ListNode with the above structure.

```
const myObj = { idKey: "myKey", parentKey: 'myParentKey', childrenKey: "myChildrenKey" } as const;
type values = typeof myObj[keyof typeof myObj]; // type values = "myKey" | "myParentKey" | "myChildrenKey"
// What do do next?
```

Comment: Hey, can you provide the `blocks` variable?

Comment: Added more code on how to use this in practice together with blocks variable example.

Comment: What's going on with the `| null` in your types?  Your implementation doesn't add `null` anywhere; maybe you mean `undefined`?  That's different.

Comment: also, which ts version are you using?

Comment: Seems like the "default" bit is the annoying part, otherwise it would be fairly straightforward.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mbv44m) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yeah that works only if the default params are provided. Ideally though I want the defaults there since it would be cumbersome to provide them everytime.

Also I want his function to be called from both Typescript and JavaScript without changes. I guess there is a limit to what TypeScript can do.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused.  What do you mean "only if the default params are provided"?  As far as I know [my suggestion](https://tsplay.dev/WPg3Ym) just adds typings to your existing function and doesn't change anything about how it works.  What "limit" are you seeing to what TypeScript can do?  If there's something specific that doesn't work or doesn't behave as you expect about my suggestion, could you demonstrate with code?  I'm not seeing it.